# Delta dirac function in the Channel model

Tags: channel

I have a question about the channel model below.

[image]

theta, phi denotes AoA(Angle of Arrival), AoD(Angle of Departure) from receiver and transmitter.

I know that channel impulse response is the sum of individual responses.

But the channel model above considers AoA(Angle of Arrival) and AoD(Angle of Departure) and those are expressed in the delta Dirac function.

What is the exact meaning of this AoA and AoD in delta Dirac function?

Comment: k, n are the time and sub-carrier in OFDM and m is a multipath component

Comment: it actually "means" the same as everywhere else. Do you know how to deal with Delta dirac functions in general, i.e. if I say $h(\tau) = \frac12\delta(\tau-2)$, do you understand what that means?

Comment: also note that I would call the notation of $(2)$ "unclean": $h(k,n,\ell)$ is actually a function(al) in $(\tau, \theta, \phi)$, but it's not taking these as arguments. If it helps, I think $(2)$ would be easier to understand if you called it $h_{k,n,\ell}(\tau,\theta,\phi)$ instead. $k, n$ and $\ell$ are more like indices "selecting" the $h(\tau,\theta,\phi)$ from a large table of impulse responses.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I know what is the Dirac delta function works but in the formula, three Dirac delta functions are multiplied.. so I always 0+0j for channel impulse response. I can understand that tau is a time delay, but I don't know the meaning of angle in Dirac delta function.

Comment: hm? No, $h(k,n,l) = 0$ isn't true for all points! Also, it really doesn't help much to think of a Dirac delta in terms of the *function* $h$, but you need to think about what happens when you insert $h$ in an integral. After all, you convolve things with $h$!

Comment: Thank you, Marcus. I will think about it